# Passing a non-const reference without a named object?

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing

I have a class `StreamRead` that represents a file, that I'd like to pass to a constructor for other classes, like a `Bitmap` for instance.  However, I cannot pass an unnamed temporary to `Bitmap` directly.

```
Bitmap::Bitmap(StreamRead & in) {
    // "in" cannot be const because StreamRead's reading operations
    // change the file position
    ...
}

int main() {
    Bitmap image(StreamRead("filename.png")); // illegal
}
```

I've found three ways to address this.  The last one is the one I'm using because it's ergonomic, without using `mutable`, but I worry it may not be well defined in C++:

- Always making named temporaries when making StreamRead objects
- Making the file position member in `StreamRead` `mutable` and it's reading methods `const`
- **Giving `StreamRead` a method that returns a reference to itself, and chaining this call on the constructor.**

So my code now looks like this:

```
StreamRead & StreamRead::pass() {
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    // legal, but is this well-defined?
    Bitmap image(StreamRead("filename.png").pass()); 
}
```

Can I depend on `pass()` always providing a valid reference?  Or is the C++ compiler allowed to do funky stuff like destroy the `StreamRead` object immediately after it gets the reference to it, then call the constructor to Bitmap with the dangling reference?

Comment: Sounds like `Bitmap` should accept rvalue reference instead of lvalue ref. Or possibly both (as overloads). Or get filename as string and open `StreamRead` by itself. `pass()` method like this is the least readable solution, regardless of whether it is UB or not.

Comment: You could define a generic `T& antimove(T&&)`, would be less an abuse of `StreamRead` and its interface. But Yksisarvinen is correct, you are focusing on the wrong component to bridge the gap in the interface.

Comment: You could use a templated constructor taking a 'universal' reference e.g. 
`template<class Stream> Bitmap(Stream&& stream) { process(std::forward<Stream>(stream)); };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you third approach should work fine, because the scope of the function parameters extend until the end of the function.

There are some other options for you to have the code work too. First you can declare the function parameter with const lvalue reference qualifier

```cpp
Bitmap::Bitmap(const StreamRead & in) {}
```

Or you can do universal reference

```cpp
template<typename T>
Bitmap::Bitmap(T&& in) {}
```

The reason you can't pass an unnamed temporary to the original function is because an unnamed temporary is a prvalue, and your paramter has lvalue reference qualifier, which means the reference's value can be changed. However, prvalues don't bind to a name so you can't really change it. You can change the value of a variable that has value 5, but you can't change the pure value 5.